# For increasing or decreasing functions within an interval $I$, why can $f(b) \leq f(a)$ and $f(b) \geq f(a)$ for all $b$ $>$ $a$?

Tags: functions

### Definitions

A function $f(x)$  **increases** on an interval $I$ if $f(b) \geq f(a)$ for all $b > a$, where $a$,$b$ $\in$ $I$

A function $f(x)$ **decreases** on an interval $I$ if $f(b) \leq f(a)$ for all $b > a$, where $a$,$b$ $\in$ $I$

### Question

Why can $f(b) = f(a)$ when $f(x)$ isn't increasing or decreasing on an interval?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you familiar with constant functions?  If $f(x)=42$ for every $x$, then $f$ is simultaneously (*non-strictly*) monotonic increasing as well as (*non-strictly*) monotonic decreasing.

Comment: @JMoravitz So $f(a)$ can be equal to $f(b)$ since $f(x)$ may be a constant function?

Comment: Your two statements are not true.  A function may or may not strictly increase or decrease given those conditions.  It does *not* strictly increase if there is *any* case where $f(b) \le f(a)$ for *some* $b > a$.

Comment: @JMoravitz When we talk or monotonic functions, we're talking about the entire function whose first derivative does not change sign. I'm talking about non-strictly increasing and decreasing functions. Thus, we refer to an interval of the function and not the entire function, right?

Comment: @fleablood When say a function does not strictly increase or decrease, we're talking about whether it increases or decreases within an interval, right? Check: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingFunction.html

Comment: If you want to specify that you are talking only about an interval, then say that you are talking about an interval... "*non-strictly monotonic increasing over the interval I.*"  If you don't specify an interval, it is commonly understood you are talking about being monotone over the entire domain

Comment: @JMoravitz I mention an interval in my definition, right? I don't understand what you mean by being specific.

Comment: I'll try to say it again.  "*When we say a function does not strictly increase or decrease, we're talking about whether it increases or decreases (specifically) within an interval, right?*"  No.  We are only talking about it increasing or decreasing specifically within an interval *if we say that we are specifically talking about it with regards to an interval*.  There is no requirement however that we are specifically limiting ourselves to talking about an interval and we may talk about it strictly increasing or decreasing, etc... over the entire domain.

Comment: We are perfectly allowed to talk about a strictly increasing function without ever mentioning an interval... in which case we are talking about it being a strictly increasing function over the entire domain.  Intervals do not appear in the definition *unless* we are defining "increasing *over an interval*" as opposed to more simply "increasing (in general)"

Comment: YOu are confusing "not strictly increasing" with "increasing but not strictly".  For instance $f(x) = \sin x$ is not strictly increasing because... it's not.  But $f(x)$ is not monotonic.  A strictly increasing function is one where for all $b>a$ we have $f(b) > f(a)$.  But an increasing (but not strictly) function is one where for all $b > a$ we have $f(b) \ge f(a)$.  Now if a function is *strictly* increasing or decreasing we can not ever have $f(b) = f(a)$. But if a function is increasing (but not strictly) we can as $f(b)\le f(a)$.

Comment: You should mention in you question that you are assuming the functions are monotonic.

Comment: @fleablood I have a question. When we say that a function is increasing but not strictly, does this mean we're considering an interval?

Comment: Why are you asking him?  What was unsatisfactory about the answer to that I already gave?  He'll just say the exact same thing I did in perhaps different language... Please go ahead and ask fleablood as well and hear his answer... but seriously..... I don't understand what is so hard about this or why you insist on intervals being necessary to the conversation.

Comment: "When we say that a function is increasing but not strictly, does this mean we're considering an interval?" No.  It could be increasing over the entire real numbers.  In fact *unless* we specify an interval we assume one means over the entire reals.  The function $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing (everywhere). The function $f(x) = \sin x$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[0, \frac \pi 2]$ but not nescessarily off the interval.  The function $f(x) =(x+1)^3$ if $x \le -1; f(x) =(x-1)^3$ if $x \ge 1$ and $f(x) =0$ if $-1< x< 0$. Is an increasing function but not *strictly* increasing.

Comment: @fleablood Alright, functions that are increasing but not strictly are many-one then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Definitions:

A function $f$ is said to be **monotonic increasing** if whenever $a> b$ we have $f(a)\geq f(b)$ for all $a,b$ in the domain

A function $f$ is said to be **strictly increasing** if whenever $a>b$ we have $f(a)>f(b)$ for all $a,b$ in the domain

A function $f$ is said to be *monotonic increasing* **on an interval $I$** if whenever $a>b$ we have $f(a)\geq f(b)$ for all $a,b$ **in the interval**

Similarly the above can be defined using **decreasing** instead such as monotonic decreasing meaning that if whenever $a>b$ we have $f(a)\leq f(b)$ for all $a,b$ in the domain.

---

The phrasing "monotonic increasing" to refer to $a>b\implies f(a)\geq f(b)$ as opposed to "*non-strictly increasing*" is preferred to avoid confusion with functions who do not satisfy the property of strictly increasing.  When you hear someone say that a function is "*non-strictly increasing*" they mean a function who is monotonic increasing.  They do not mean a function who does not satisfy the property of being strictly increasing.

A function who is simultaneously monotonic increasing and monotonic decreasing is necessarily a constant function.  This is the case since supposing we were to have some $a>b$, by the fact it is monotonic increasing we have $f(a)\geq f(b)$.  By the fact it is monotonic decreasing we have $f(b)\geq f(a)$.  As we have then $f(a)\geq f(b)\geq f(a)$, the only way this is true is if $f(a)=f(b)$.  As such, we have the function is constant.

Now... as for a function who is neither strictly increasing nor strictly decreasing, there are many examples.  All that is required is that there be some examples of $a,b$ where we increase and other examples of $a,b$ where we decrease.  For example, the sine function at times increases and at other times decreases.

As for a function who is simultaneously strictly increasing and strictly decreasing, such a function can not exist.  For contradiction, suppose such a function did exist and suppose $a>b$.  Then as it is strictly increasing we have $f(a)>f(b)$.  Similarly as it is strictly decreasing we have $f(a)<f(b)$.  But then $f(a)>f(b)>f(a)$ and so $f(a)>f(a)$ which is impossible.

Comment: Pretty thorough..... nice.

Comment: @JMoravtiz Do functions that do not strictly increase nor strictly decrease receive a name? For example, the sine function.

Comment: @Nameless Unlikely, since there's nothing special about them (there is something special about the sine, but you can easily construct arbitrary functions which don't increase or decrease, so it doesn't really make sense to study such a category of functions).

Answer (score 2):

Some definitions.  Functions can do anything they bloody well want. Increase, decrease, do neither, sometimes do one and other spots do the other.

A function is *increasing* (maybe strictly, maybe not) if for every $b > a$ we always have $f(b) \ge f(a)$.  The function is *strictly* increasing if for every $b > a$ we always have $f(b) > f(a)$.

If we have $b > a$ and $f(b) = f(a) = k$, it is not possible that $f$ is strictly increasing because $f(b) \not > f(a)$.  However as $k \ge k$ and $f(b) \ge f(a)$ it is *possible* that $f$ is increasing but not strictly.  But if that were so for every $x: a< x < b$ we must have $k = f(a) \le f(x) \le f(b) = k$ so $k \le f(x) \le k$ so $f(x) =k$.  So *if* $f$ is increasing and if $f(b) = f(a)=k$ then $f(x) = k$ for all $x: a\le x \le b$.

However a function where $f(b) = f(a)$ doesn't need to be increasing at all.  we could have $f(x)= x^2$ and $f(2) = f(-2)$.  Or we could have $f(x) = \sin x$ and $f(2\pi +\frac \pi 6) = f(\frac \pi 6)$.  But we are told $f$ is increasing and we are told $f(b) =f(a)$ for some $b > a$, the we must conclude: $f$ is not increasing strictly, and $f(x)$ is constant for all $x: a \le x \le b$.

The same definitions and results are for decreasing and strictly decreasing but the definition of decreasing is for every $b > a$ we always have $f(b) \le f(a)$.

A function that is either increasing or decreasing is called *monotonic*.

If we restrict every thing we are considering to an interval $[m,n]$ and for all $m \le a < b \le n$ we have $f(a) \le f(b)$ but we have no idea what the function is doing *outside* the interval, we say $f$ is increasing *on the interval*.

....

So to answer your question if we have $a < b$ and we have $f(a) = f(b)$ we can have $f$ be both increasing and decreasing on the interval, $[a,b]$ but only if $f(x) = k$, a constant, for all $x$ an the interval.  And we can have $f$ be both increasing and decreasing everywhere but only if $f(x) = k$ everywhere.

But we can't have either $f$ *strictly* increasing or strictly decreasing.

And of course we can simply have $f(x)$ be *neither* increasing or decreasing.

I think you are tripping up on definitions.  If $a < b$ and $f(a) = f(b)$ that in and of itself does not mean anything (other than the function is not one-to-one) and isn't unusual....

.... or did you mean that $f(a) = f(b)$ for *ALL* $a,b$.  If $f(a) =f(b)$ for *all* $a,b$ then $f$ is constant function.

A constant function is monotonic, it never decreases and it never increases.  And, technically (albeit counter-intuitively) by the *definition*, "If for all $b > a$ we always have $f(b) \ge f(a)$" is *true*, we do technically have a constant function *is* an increasing function.  But a *strictly* increasing function.

Think of it this way.  An "increasing" function is one that never decreases so it always is either increasing or staying constant.  That includes one that stays constant forever.  But a *strictly* increasing function is on that is *always* increasing and never decreases and never stays constant.

Answer (score 1):

You must read "(not strictly) increasing" rather than "not (strictly increasing)". $f$ constant fulfills both the (not strictly) increasing and (not strictly) decreasing conditions.

Comment: I get what you mean, I chose the wrong words..

Comment: I have  question. Is the constant function the only type of function that fulfill both conditions?

Comment: @Nameless Yes, the constant (*over the interval / over the entire domain*) functions are the only functions who are simultaneously (*weakly*) monotonic increasing and (*weakly*) monotonic decreasing (*over the interval / over the entire domain*).